# how to pass Intergers between view controllers in swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

This is my code and it's not working. LightOrDark and LightDark are Integers and should be equal when the app changes views.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "LightSegue") {
        if let MinigameView = segue.destinationViewController as? MinigameView {
       self.LightOrDark = MinigameView.LightDark
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your complete code of the two view controllers you're using?

Comment: by code convention, you should not start variable names with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.LightOrDark = MinigameView.LightDark` this statement sets `MinigameView.LightDark` to current class's `LightOrDark`.

You need to set `LightDark` of `MinigameView` so your code should be like,

```
   MinigameView.LightDark = self.LightOrDark
```

And you should follow naming standard. variable or instance name should be start with lower case not upper case.

so your instance name should be `lightOrDark and minigameView` instead of `LightOrDark  and MinigameView`.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thank you very much i couldn't find the answers anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong: `self.LightOrDark = MinigameView.LightDark`. Change it to:
`MinigameView.LightDark = self.LightOrDark`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the destination viewcontroller property

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let destVc = segue.destinationViewController as? MinigameView else {
       return
    }
    destVc.LightOrDark = self.LightDark
}}
```